# Releasing objects in animations (Unity)

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

I have made an animation in 3ds max where a human holds a spear and throws it. Then I imported it to Unity. I tried to detach/disconnect the spear during the animation with `spear.transform.parent = null;`. 
The spear doesn't release, however. I believe it could be because of the connection to the animation. Anyway, I have made a connection between the spear and the skeleton in 3ds max. In 3ds max, the spear doesn't actually release from the hand, which is intended.

I am very much looking forward to your replies.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want your 3ds max animation to contain any updates for the spear you just want to animate the "hand" which will hold the spear and the rest of the body.

Once you import the animation the spear is made a child of the hand. This way it will follow the hand so long as it's a child (normal parent/child gameobject behaviour), as soon as you unparent the spear it will not be getting any updates from the animation and not have a parent to follow (and you can apply a force or activate it's own movement script or whatever).

Depending on how your model is setup you might need a "holding point" bone rather than using the "hand" bone to resolve issues with rotation/positioning the carried item.